# Style AutoCompleteBox Error Indicator

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit, autocompletebox

Is it possible to change the style of the red rectangle that appear when the AutoCompleteBox from the WPF Toolkit has an error? I successfully changed it on the TextBox just creating a new style for the control but no matter what I do with the AutoCompleteBox I can't get rid of that red rectangle. Even if I remove the style like this:

```
<input:AutocompleteBox Style="{x:Null}"/>
```

I cannot see the control but if I have an error on the control binding, it still shows a red line! What I would really like is that the AutoCompleteBox use the internal TextBox validation indicator but first I need to remove that outer rectangle. Any ideas on how to do this or what is creating that red rectangle?

Answer (score 0):

`AutocompleteBox` consists of `TextBox`, `SelectionAdapter`, `DropDownToggle` and `Popup`.
And error-sate style, that you've described, is defined in `TextBoxStyle`:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:AutoCompleteBox">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:AutoCompleteBox">
                <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <TextBox IsTabStop="True" x:Name="Text" Style="{TemplateBinding TextBoxStyle}" Margin="0" />
...
```

To change `TextBox` behavior when error - just change it's style.

Comment: That is exactly what i was expecting too - but it did not work. I have my textBoxes working fine with my new style but setting it to the AutoCompleteBox TextBoxStyle did not worked. The textbox get the new style but it doesn't indicate error on the textbox but outside of it. It seems that the autocompletebox somehow creates a outter border to the textbox. It is really frustrating. I'm trying to find what is happening on the AutoCompleteBox source code, without success so far :/